# Problem in using amsmath and mathastext packages

Tags: luatex, amsmath, mathastext

I am trying to use Arial fonts and fira-math fonts and compiling with lualatex. I am also using
mathastext. However there is a problem.  The `\begin{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix}` doesn't work.
Here is a MWE, compiled with lualatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{firamath-otf}
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.2]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\begin{document}
    This is running text.
\[\cos 2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1\]    
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&2\\
A&b&1\\
c&X&Z
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a work around for this? I want to use fira-math so, loading fontspec with no-math option is not possible I think.

Comment: firamath-otf loads the unicode-math package. You shouldn't use this together with mathastext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use something like this. You can [download Fira Math font from GitHub](https://github.com/firamath/firamath) or use `firamath-otf`, of course. My advice is not to use text fonts as math fonts; they are missing a number of font dimens and glyphs needed for good math. So using them for math is always only a work-around.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[mathrm=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\setmainfont{Arial}%[Scale=1.2] too large .. 

\begin{document}    
This is running text.
\[
  \int_0^{\mathrm{\pi}} \sin x \, \mathrm{d}x = 2
\]
\[
  \cos 2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1 
\]    
\[
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b & 2 \\
    A & b & 1 \\
    c & X & Z
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, using text fonts for Mathematics is not my choice. It is forced upon me.  I am now using arial for mathematics text in pdflatex with the help of several crude hacks. I was wondering if it will be any easier in lualatex or xetex.   I will try out your solution instead of using mathastext..